# Nginx - настройка locations (proxy_pass)

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, nginx, proxy

Есть Node API работающее на порте 8080
Как настроить nginx locations (proxy_pass), если есть такие locations:
`/accounts
/events
/providers
/users`

Причем у каждого из них может быть например так:
`/events/get/:id`

Answer (score 1):

Проксируете на 8080 порт. Например:

```
location ^~/accounts {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    ...
}
```

Тоже самое и для других локаций.